# Using Graph API to post to fan page as the fan page (not as a user)

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

Need help. I have Graph API code that uses an auth token with offline permissions to post to a fan page as me. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to post to a fan page *as the fan page*. The API Explorer only works as an individual. When I do a "use facebook as..." for the page and try to use the explorer, it tells me it has to revert me back to being me first. So the auth token is for my personal account, not the fan page account. The auth token has the manage_pages permissions, but that just lets me post to the page as me.

Anyone have an answer or know where I can find one? Search on FB, Bing, Google all pull up nothing on this specific issue.

The point being, of course, that while I could have the automation post as me, that means that the post doesn't show as being from the page, so most people won't see it. Need adult supervision! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) under the title `App Login`.  All the information you need is there...
You have to request an access token for the page and not for the user - then all post you make are onbehalf of the page.

---

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
     grant_type=client_credentials
```

Fetching that url will give you the correct access token to post as your page.

Comment: Lix, I did that, and got the App token and tried to post using it. It still posted as me, when I'm logged in, or gave me an auth error when I was not. The app token seems to have no concept of "offline_access" to allow it to be used at any time.

Am I missing the obvious? :-)

Comment: what language are you using? php?

Comment: I have that access token. When I attempt to use it, I get back: "Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" ... but I can't seem to find where I can authorize the application to post.

Comment: How do I do that? I can't find any place to grant applications permissions, only users.

Comment: Closer. I followed the steps to get the new token and am using it, and now I get this error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id

Comment: FIXED! One muse use this token to post to /me/feed and not to the /[pageid]/feed of the page. The token knows which page to use, so you don't have to specify it! Thanks for your help, Lix, you led me down the path ;)

Comment: sure no problem - thats the idea - when you use an app/page token the "user" becomes the page.

Answer (score 2):

To post to fanpage u not only need a manage page permission but the most importantly u need a **page access token**,here's the code for getting page access token.

```
$pages_arr = array(
'access_token'=>$access_token ,
'fields'=>'access_token' 

);


// Get Page access_token
$page_token = $fb->api('/'.$pageid, 'get',$pages_arr);

$page_access_token=$page_token['access_token']; // get page access_token

// you got the page access token,now use it to do anything on page as page
```

Answer (score 0):

See my blog post "how to post TO a page and AS the page" at http://bobbelderbos.com/2011/11/facebook-api-post-to-page-and-as-page/

Once you have the manage_pages permission each page requires its own access code.

See the blog post for further explanation, demo and code download.